# How can i shift my chosen posts to a subdirectory?

Tags: directory, subdomains

I want to shift my chosen posts to a subdirectory. like...
this is a post link
mysite.com/post-number-one

want to do
mysite.com/subdirectory/post-number-one

Comment: Change your permalink structure in WordPress settings to use the category.

Comment: this is fine, but I don't want to shift all posts, just some of my all posts

Comment: right but, i don't want to shift my all posts to subdirectory, just some of those posts

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a built-in setting for this that can be set in the Settings > Permalinks screen.

Choose "Custom Structure" and add in your desired prefix/subdirectory at the start of that input field with a slash after it.

```
/subdirectory/%postname%
```